# My website frequently redirect to a different advertisement URL

Tags: jquery, redirect, errors, sql, ads

Can you guys help me to figure out why it's happening? Its mainly happen from my search engine result. From Google search when I click on my website it will redirect to a scam website.

*Note: now its look like happening everywhere on my website. I even affected when I click on a post, but it's bit rear then search engine.*

this is the web address I am affected by:

http://mobile4494.greenyourday112.agency/2675651026/?utm_campaign=bKMuT7EMVXU5Z6UvvSHONGlfu-yV43iC8T8uYixAFxs1&t=main9_143c45092c890a12fd&f=1

and my website: https://toptenflash.com/.

It so so frustrating always redirect to another website that you don't want. Please help me to figure it out

Comment: You've probably been hacked. Please refer to the official FAQ for steps to take: https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

Comment: Probably XXS'ED or sql injected, you should take action and search how to secure your website

Comment: I would contact your host ASAP, they can probably help you faster than you trying to figure it out.